# IE lets you open Outlook window through ActiveX control and set its HTML content. Can Chrome do that?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, outlook

IE lets you open Outlook window through ActiveX control and prepopulate its HTML content.
This comes very usefull for our sales staff.

Is there any way do this from Chrome ?